# Active Link Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript for making sidebar links active. This is the code. Now my link get active when url is `http://localhost:8000/jobs/`. But when the link is `http://localhost:8000/jobs/add/` then it gets inactive. I was using `slice, replace and split` but it was working for `http://localhost:8000/jobs` like this type of url with no ending with `slash(\)`. But my every url is ending with slash that why i have added those line of code having `comment : Customly Added`

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');

//var current = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');

var current = location.pathname;// Customly Added
$('.nav li a', sidebar).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (current === "") {
    //for root url
    if ($this.attr('href').indexOf("index.html") !== -1) {
      $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
      if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  } else {
    //for other url

    // if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {

    if ($this.attr('href')==current) { // Customly Added
      $(this).parents('.nav-item').last().addClass('active');
      if ($(this).parents('.sub-menu').length) {
        $(this).closest('.collapse').addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The code you commented removes leading/trailing slashes on `current` - you should apply the same `.replace` to the url you're testing, eg `$this.attr("href").replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '') == current` (having put it back on `current`)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve / match on / not match on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the end slash(/) using Regex.

```js
    var current = location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, "");
    console.log(current);
```

Comment: Not the most descriptive of what `pathname` is, best to just try it out on a few pages so you know what "the path" is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: You are right, but the solution is question specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
  <a href="/">home</a>
  <a href="/work">work</a>
</nav>
```

what you can do is on page load/change you can check pathname against href and add a class if true

```
const { children: links } = document.querySelector('nav');

function addActiveClass({ href, classList }) {
  const currentPath = location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, "");

  href ===  currentPath ?
    classList.add('active') :
    classList.remove('active');
}

document.onload = () => Array.from(links).forEach(addActiveClass)
```